# How to test in which mode of magicness Vim is?

Tags: substitute

Vim can be in four or more magic states.

In vim help documentation there is plenty to read about, all presuming that the user knows the current state of magicness.

When a complicated many lines long :substitute does not (after typing of other newlines), it would be helpful to ask Vim in which magic state Vim is (and yet better: to see how backslashes in this state to use).

Is such a short query possible?

Regards

Comment: Just to be sure I suppose you mean: very-magic (`\v`),  magic (`\m`), non-magic (`\M`) and very-much-non-magic (`\V`)

Comment: No. Vim can only be in two "magic states": "magic" and "nomagic", see `:help 'magic'`. Moreover, `\m`, `\M`, `\v`, and `\V` only have some effect *when the command is executed* so there is no such thing as a "current state of magicness" that covers all ground. What you call "current state of magicness" is the one you put yourself in.

Answer (score 1):

> it would be helpful to ask Vim in which magic state Vim is […] Is such a short query possible?

You can ask for the state of the magic mode before a search (including for a global operation or a substitution) with the following Ex command:

```
:set magic?
```

> (and yet better: to see how backslashes in this state to use).

Ex/Vi is one of the successors of Ed which bring RegExp to us (standardised to BRE since then) That means some few characters has special/magic meaning, and Ex/Vi add a switch to disable them (anchors always keep their meaning) for newbies who can be confused with them when searching litteral text (with dot for example.) However the traditional behaviour is on by default and here's how I summary this option in my courses:

| magic | nomagic | for |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `.` | `\.` | any character |
| `*` | `\*` | optionaly repeat many times |
| `~` | `\~` | previous substitution string |
| `[]` | `\[]` | characters set |

Vim come with handy substitute alternatives for you, so you don't have to know the magicness state:

- `:smagic/RE/replace/opt` (short `sma`) …or `s/\mRE/replace/opt` …is like doing `set magic` then `s/RE/replace/opt` and back to initial state
- `:snomagic/RE/replace/opt` (short `snom`) …or `s/\MRE/replace/opt` …is like doing `set nomagic` then `s/RE/replace/opt` and back to initial state

> Vim can be in four or more magic states.

As described previously, there're only two option states, magic or not. But Vim also extends them (very or very not) with dedicated escape letters I've introduced in the list above: `\m` (magic), `\v` (very magic —makes all unaccentuated letters special), `\M` (not magic; traditional way listed in the table above), `\V` (very not magic —disable Vim additional escapes too). With those four keys, you don't need to bother the maginess state, but they're not four magic states you can permanently toggle.

Comment: In a very long expression using `\v`, `\V` switching several time from one mode to another youcan get lost and don't know the mode you are at a given position of the expression. I read the OP demand as a way, colonization, status to get informed of the mode at a given position in the expression.

Comment: Oh… Sound both interesting and strange because i don't see why one should do more than one switch in the same expression, but why not. That makes my long answer irelevant (out of topic) :)

Comment: Thanks for the edition @Mass :)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt then the question should be rewritten to reflect the actual intent.